# Does using Oracle TDE guarantees compliance to HIPAA, for persisting sensitive data?

Tags: encryption, hipaa, oracle, sensitive-data-exposure

Persisting sensitive customer pharma data is becoming more challenging with stricter HIPAA compliance guidelines, wondering if TDE solves it entirely or are there any gaps that a developer/dba should be aware of.